# OnTriggerEnter and OnTriggerExit called twice despite checking it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have read a lot of questions about this problem but i couldn't solve it yet. I have one ball with a Sphere Collider and an invisible wall to restart the ball when it passes through it (on the onTriggerExit method). The problem is that i've not been able to solve it, even with a boolean to avoid entering the method.

```
public class ballRestart : MonoBehaviour
{
    shootController instance;
    bool isColliding;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        instance = Camera.main.GetComponent<shootController>();
        isColliding = false;
    }


    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        Debug.Log("TeEnter: " + isColliding);
        if (!isColliding)
        {
            isColliding = true;
            Debug.Log("TRIGGERED: " + isColliding);
        }

    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider hit)
    {
        Debug.Log("TeExit: " + isColliding);
        if (isColliding)
        {
            instance.initializeBall();
            isColliding = false;
            Debug.Log("exit");
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

[Here is the output of the Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdlQb.png)

As you see, it enters twice each time the ball enters the collider and twice each time the ball exits the same collider. I don't know what happens here.

Comment: Could you confirm that you haven't accidently added the script multiple times? For instance on child elements or so.

Comment: Yes, the script is only added to a GameObject wich has no childs.

Comment: How many objects are in your scene?

Comment: debug with `Debug.Log("TRIGGERED: " + col.gameObject.name);`

Comment: Its no unity's error for sure.  check the debug, and how are you moving your object?  if your just unprotectedly jumping the transform around, this can happen.

Comment: I am moving my object setting its velocity and adding a Force. @EnderDoe

Comment: @Eddge In my scene there are 10 objects or so but the only one that moves is the ball.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you have 2 colliders on your object, each of them causes event triggering. Check your components and child objects.

P.s.: I know it is old question, but my answer can be helpful for others.